# XCode 4.2 Objective-C ARC LLVM Errors: current parser token '-' and generation of compound statement ('{}')

Tags: objective-c, llvm, xcode4.2, automatic-ref-counting

After upgrading to Objective-C ARC (Automatic reference counting) my code no longer compiles and gives me these weird errors:

```
/Users/teacher/drawingapp/Main/Source/PurchaseThemeOptionVC.m 
1. /Users/teacher/drawingapp/Main/Source/PurchaseThemeOptionVC.m:52:1: current parser token '-'
2. /Users/teacher/drawingapp/Main/Source/PurchaseThemeOptionVC.m:39:1: LLVM IR generation of declaration 'PurchaseThemeOptionVC::viewDidLoad'
3. /Users/teacher/drawingapp/Main/Source/PurchaseThemeOptionVC.m:39:21: LLVM IR generation of compound statement ('{}')
clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault
clang: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal 2 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've looked through the source file several times and I can't see anything wrong with it.

What do these errors mean?

- current parser token '-'
- generation of declaration 'PurchaseThemeOptionVC::viewDidLoad'
- generation of compound statement ('{}')

Comment: Could you edit the question and paste the relevant source code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay I've solved it through a process of elimination.

Inside the viewDidLoad function of PurchaseThemeOptionVC.m there is this line of code:

```
[InAppPurchaseManager sharedInAppPurchaseManager].themeStatusDelegate = self;
```

And inside the InAppPurchaseManager singleton, there is a delegate reference which has a setter, but no @property for it.

```
@interface InAppPurchaseManager : NSObject <SKProductsRequestDelegate, ...> {

    ...

    id<ThemeStatusDelegate> themeStatusDelegate;
}

...

- (void)setThemeStatusDelegate:(id<ThemeStatusDelegate>)delegate;
```

Now if I understand this correctly, the setThemeStatusDelegate: is the setter and gets called automatically when a variable is assigned to themeStatusDelegate. And this seemed to work fine until I upgraded from 'LLVM GCC 4.2' to the 'Apple LLVM Compiler 3.0'

I've now fixed the problem by calling the setter directly:

```
[[InAppPurchaseManager sharedInAppPurchaseManager] setThemeStatusDelegate:self];
```

Now unless I've missing something, there appears to be a bug in the 'Apple LLVM Compiler 3.0'. Thoughts?

Comment: Properties are supposed to be type-safe, so shouldn't work if you haven't declared the property even though they're implemented by messages that the class may respond to.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it turned out that I put in my ViewController

```
 self.data = 0
```

While I didn't have a 'data' property defined. This didn't give an error: Undefined property, but it gave the parser errors you specified. Maybe it helps someone

---

Weirdly enough, if I changed that line to:

```
 self.tralala = 0
```

which is also undefined, it gives a proper error message.